# Create directory with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am having a Java Project managed by Maven. I want to create .jar file of the project automatically with Maven such that after Maven executes the task, there will be something like this:

```
directory_i_want_to_create
    my_project.jar
    config.json
    input_folder
```

As my project needs to read input from input folder and config.json as above (so that I can run the command line to execute the jar), how can I create such `directory_i_want_to_create` like above with Maven ?

Comment: Look into Copy Resources: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html  I've used it to copy things to arbitrary locations, and it can be attached to any phase.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an [Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html). Configuration would looks like:

**pom.xml**

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/default.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

<id>default</id>

<formats>
    <format>dir</format>
</formats>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>directory_i_want_to_create</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>input_folder</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: its mental that this is the correct answer for how to get maven to create a directory :)

Answer (score 1):

Small amount less XML if you use Ant

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <mkdir dir="target/directory_i_want_to_create" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: If you do that a lot you can put the <goals> part in <pluginManagement> then its _only_ 13 lines of xml tro run  mkdir